# Android - How to add selection from Spinner to EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

what I'm trying to do is make a selection from a spinner in android and then whatever is selected to be added to an edittext box.  The code I have so far is this...

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
          new OnItemSelectedListener() {

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

      edittext.setText("");

     }

     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
              //add some code here
          }
      );
```

Problem is this seems to be run even before the spinner is selected so it always sets my edittext to "".  Ideally I would like to have it set the text to the selection made in the spinner.  So, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

At startup, your spinner will get its defaultvalue, that counts as a selection.
Do a `boolean FirstTime` or something like that.

You probably initialize your spinner from some array or something?
The function actually looks like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int position, long id);
```

So just use the position variable

```
{
    edittext.setText(myArray[position]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getItem` method in the adapter to get the object that is shown. Like this:

```
onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  editText.setText((String) adapter.getItem(position));
}
```